# libtcl8.4.so and libtk8.4.so are missing

Tags: centos, tcl, redhat, fedora, tk-toolkit

When I was trying to execute tcl scripts with blt and wish, I encouter the following errors:

blt:

```
[user@centos-linux ~]$ bltsh
bltsh: error while loading shared libraries: libtcl8.4.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

wish:

```
[user@centos-linux NEW]$ ./Tide.tcl > NUL
/usr/local/bin/bltwish: error while loading shared libraries: libtk8.4.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have already installed tcl and tk 8.4.9, and blt from ftp://ftp.ccp4.ac.uk/tcltk/TclTk-8.4/README.html with the packag tcltkblt-8.4.9.i386.bin.tar.gz.

It seems that libtcl8.4.so and libtk8.4.so are missing. I wonder if these errors can be fixed simply by installing libtcl8.4 and libtk8.4 on CentOS 7.5 and how?

I cannot find a way to install libtcl8.4.9 and libtk8.4.9. On the other hand, I cannot upgrade to tcl/tk 8.5 or 8.6 since the scripts require me to run tcl/tk 8.4.

Answer (score 1):

> I have already installed `tcl` and `tk` 8.4.9, and blt from <…> with the packag `tcltkblt-8.4.9.i386.bin.tar.gz`.

I doubt the "tcltk**blt**-8.4.9.i386.bin.tar.gz" package has really installed Tcl and Tk—I bet it merely instaled the BLT package.

Searching [this list of packages](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/) for "tcl-8" reveals that CentOS 7 has only Tcl and Tk 8.5 packaged, not 8.4.

As 8.4 is dirt-old, I'd suggest taking another route and working towards getting BLT built against Tcl 8.5.

Doing a [usual search routine](https://www.google.com/search?q=Tcl+BLT+epel) yields [this package](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/blt-2.4-47.z.el7.x86_64.rpm.html). Please read the "Install Howto" on that page and proceed accordingly.

Also please make sure to remove the BLT package you have already installed.

Comment: 8.4 is fully out of support; for anyone (foolish) who wants to build it, the source is online and they can fight with compilers and build-chains themselves.

Comment: I must admit I missed the «On the other hand, I cannot upgrade to tcl/tk 8.5 or 8.6 since the scripts require me to run tcl/tk 8.4.» bit. Still, Tcl is pretty much backwards-compatible; @spungcl9k, care to elaborate on what fails in your scripts when you attempt to run them with 8.5? (A separate question tagged `[tcl]` would be fine.)